# UnicodeDecodeError while starting the app under Windows with Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

The problem is that when i try to start the application (app.py)
i get the following error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 5: invalid start byte

The whole file app.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return 'Hello World'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1')
```

I read somewhere here on stackoverflow that this can help:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

but it doesn't change anything.
Then i changed from

```
app.run()
```

to

```
app.run(host='127.0.0.1')
```

but it doesn't work too.

I start the app under windows, so i set the env. variable as follows:

```
set FLASK_APP = app.py
```

but no matter if i run this in pycharm or in windows cmd with

```
flask run
```

I get the same error everytime.

Full error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Michał/Desktop/Michał/Zadanie/Flask_Blog/app.py", 
line 11, in <module>
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1')
  File "C:\Users\Michał\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 943, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Michał\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 990, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "C:\Users\Michał\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 943, in inner
    fd=fd,
  File "C:\Users\Michał\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 786, in make_server
    host, port, app, request_handler, passthrough_errors, ssl_context, 
fd=fd
  File "C:\Users\Michał\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 679, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, server_address, handler)
  File "C:\Users\Michał\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\socketserver.py", line 453, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Users\Michał\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\http\server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "C:\Users\Michał\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\socket.py", line 673, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 5: 
invalid start byte
```

Edit (Update) I changed the python.exe location and project location and the error still exist:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Public/Projekt/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1')
  File "C:\Users\Public\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\flask\app.py", line 943, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 990, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "C:\Users\Public\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 943, in inner
    fd=fd,
  File "C:\Users\Public\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 786, in make_server
    host, port, app, request_handler, passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd
  File "C:\Users\Public\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 679, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, server_address, handler)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 453, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Users\Public\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 673, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 5: invalid start byte
```

Comment: In all days was good rule: don't use spaces and native (Polish) letters in file/folder names. Code `0xb3` is letter `ł` in `Michał` in encoding [windows-1250](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) (PL: lepiej nie używać polskich liter (i spacji) w nazwach plików i katalogów - 0xb3 to kod litery `ł`)

Comment: oh no... Do i have to rename the computer-username? or is there any other solution for that ? :o

Comment: rename hostname - it shouldn't be problem. I think you don't have to change username.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is native letter `ł` (probably in name `Michał`) which has code `0xb3` but in `Window-1250`, not `UTF-8`.

Maybe you have this letter not only in folder name but also in hostname (computer's name) and then script has problem when it try to get this name in

```
hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
```

You can see this line error message.

Maybe if you change hostname in Windows's setting then it will works.

---

I don't use Windows but when I was using Windows (and DOS) there was always good rule: don't use native (Polish) letters (and spaces) in file/folder name. The same can be with hostname.

---

Windows may use three different encoding (Code Page) - `Window-1250` (`CP-1250`) for filenames, `CP-852` for text in console and `UTF-8` in your script. Sometimes also `LATIN2` (`ISO-8859-2`) in old HTML files.

See: image which polish code pages (encodings) on page [Python Unicode - decode & encode](https://blog.furas.pl/python-unicode-decode-encode.html)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem (PL: Niestety, ale to nie pomogło rozwiązać problemu) :(
I added "update" to my post

Comment: in your situation problem is not location but HOSTNAME - name of computer. On Linux I can see my hostname in console using commadn `hostname`. On Windows should be the same command which you can run in console/terminal/cmd.exe

Comment: test this: `import socket ; socket.gethostbyname('Michał')`

Answer (score 0):

The method `gethostbyaddr` will get the name of your computer, if it's not English, cmd will result in this error.

You need to rename your windows computer by english totally, and reboot your computer

Answer (score 0):

This issue often occurs when the computer name in Windows contains Unicode characters. It can be fixed by [change the computer name](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/rename-your-windows-10-pc-750bc75d-8ff8-e99a-b9dc-04dff566ae74) to contain only ASCII characters.

If you are not allowed to change the computer name, you can work around this problem by editing `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` to modify the hostname of `127.0.0.1`

```
127.0.0.1  my-computer
```

You can use the following method to test whether the configuration is working properly.

```py
import socket
socket.gethostbyname('127.0.0.1')
```