# Running a flask script gives a UnicodeDecodeError error

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

When I run the following python script

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello_World'
```

the console outputs this:

```
* Serving Flask app "main.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\jespe\Google Drive\Övrigt\Programmering\Python\Flask test\venv\Scripts\flask.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\jespe\google drive\övrigt\programmering\python\flask test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 967, in main
    cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:], prog_name="python -m flask" if as_module else None)
  File "c:\users\jespe\google drive\övrigt\programmering\python\flask test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\jespe\google drive\övrigt\programmering\python\flask test\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\users\jespe\google drive\övrigt\programmering\python\flask test\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\users\jespe\google drive\övrigt\programmering\python\flask test\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\users\jespe\google drive\övrigt\programmering\python\flask test\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\jespe\google drive\övrigt\programmering\python\flask test\venv\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\jespe\google drive\övrigt\programmering\python\flask test\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\jespe\google drive\övrigt\programmering\python\flask test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 852, in run_command
    run_simple(
  File "c:\users\jespe\google drive\övrigt\programmering\python\flask test\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 1052, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "c:\users\jespe\google drive\övrigt\programmering\python\flask test\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 996, in inner
    srv = make_server(
  File "c:\users\jespe\google drive\övrigt\programmering\python\flask test\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 847, in make_server
    return ThreadedWSGIServer(
  File "c:\users\jespe\google drive\övrigt\programmering\python\flask test\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 740, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, server_address, handler)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\server.py", line 140, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\socket.py", line 756, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 14: invalid continuation byte
```

OS: Windows 10
Python version: 3.8.5
Flask version 1.1.2

I opend a venv via cmd and then installed flask and tried to run the script with the above error.

Comment: Try adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of your file. (first or second line)

Comment: @OrY Didn't work, I got the same error... But thanks!

Comment: Might be duplicate of 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/28193877/3358570

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55782460/unicodedecodeerror-while-starting-the-app-under-windows-with-pycharm

Comment: Thank you @TalhaJunaid for the help! My desktopname had an 'ä' in its name, removed that and now it works!!!